# iOSアプリからPostgreSQLを使いmampにデータを送信した際のPHPエラーの件

Tags: php, objective-c, postgresql

開発初心者でございまして分かりにくい点があるかと存じますが、ご了承くださいませ。
「Objective-C」にて「AFNetworking3.0」のライブラリを活用して、サーバー上（MAMP)
にデータの送信を試みているのですが、MAMPのPHPエラーログに以下のようなエラーが発生致しております。「PostgreSQL」の経験が浅く、コードに不備があると思われますが、色々試しましたが、自力での解決ができませんでした。お分かりになる方、ご教授頂けますと幸いで御座います。宜しくお願い致します。

> ■エラー内容
>   [15-Aug-2018 06:54:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: invalid port number: "jiptsinfra016" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DatabaseClass.php on line 34
>
> ３４行目のコードは以下ございます。(Databaseclass.php)
>
> 30行目 　    $this->link=pg_connect($this->dbServer,
>   31行目 　                                    $this->dbUser,
>   32行目 　                                    $this->dbPass,
>   33行目 　                                    $this->link,
>   34行目 　                                    $this->dbName
>   35行目 　                                 )

■Databaseclass.php（サーバー上にアップしたファイル１）

```
  //内部文字コードを変更
  mb_language("uni");
  mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
  mb_http_input("auto");
  mb_http_output("utf-8");

  class Database{

     var $dbServer;
     var $dbName;
     var $dbUser;
     var $dbPass;
     var $link;
     var $db;
     var $query;

     //DB接続
     function __construct($db_name)
     {
        //DBの情報
        $this->dbServer="localhost";
        $this->dbName=$db_name;
        $this->dbUser="root";
        $this->dbPass="root";

        //ポスグレに接続
        $this->link=pg_connect($this->dbServer,
                                  $this->dbUser,
                                  $this->dbPass,
                                  $this->link,
                                  $this->dbName
                                  )
               or
               die(exit);


        //UTF-8の文字コードに変更
        $this->query=pg_query($this->link,'SET NAMES utf8');
     }

     //DBを閉じる
     public function close()
     {
        return pg_close($this->link);
     }

     //読み込むテーブルの選択
     public function select($query)
     {
        $result=pg_query($query);
        $row=array();
        $row=pg_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row;
     }

     //指定したクエリの実行
     public function query($query)
     {
         return pg_query($this->link,$query);
     }

     //JSON形式に変換用の出力
     public function jsonparse($query)
     {
        $row = pg_fetch_object($query);
        return $row;
     }
  }
  ?>
```

■send_request.php（サーバー上にアップしたファイル２）

```
  <?php
  //DatabaseClassを読み込み
   include_once "DatabaseClass.php";

  //テーブル名と追加する値が選択されているかどうか確認
  if($_POST["table_name"] && $_POST["addtext1"] 
  && $_POST["addtext2"] && $_POST["addtext3"])
  {
     //DB名設定
     $table_name = $_POST["table_name"];
     $addtext1 = $_POST["addtext1"];
     $addtext2 = $_POST["addtext2"];
     $addtext3 = $_POST["addtext3"];

     $database = new Database("test");

     //データ追加用SQL
     $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} (field_A,field_B,field_C) VALUES
      ('{$addtext1}','{$addtext2}','{$addtext3}');";

     //クエリ送信
     $query = $database->query($sql);

     //一応結果を出力用SQL
     $sql = ("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}");

     //クエリ送信
     $query = $database->query($sql);
     $json= array();


     if(strstr($table_name, 'test_json')){
        while ($row = pg_fetch_object($query)) {
            $json[] = array(
               'field_A'=> $row->field_A
               ,'field_B'=> $row->field_B
               ,'field_C' => $row->field_C
            );
        }
     }//if(strstr($table_name, 'test_json'))


     //JSON形式で出力
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
     echo json_encode($json);

     //DBを閉じる
     $database->close();

  }//if($_POST["table_name"])
  ?>
```

■Objective-C（こちらのソースは問題ないように思えます)

```
  - (void)send_request
  {
      AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
      NSDictionary* postparam = @{ @"table_name" : @"test_json",
                                   @"addtext1"   : @"add_A",
                                   @"addtext2"   : @"add_B",
                                   @"addtext3"   : @"add_C"};
          [manager POST:@"http://localhost:8888/send_request.php"
         parameters:postparam progress:nil
            success:^(NSURLSessionTask* task, id responseObject) {
                //通信成功
                NSLog(@"成功response: %@", responseObject);
            }
            failure:^(NSURLSessionTask* operation, NSError* error) {
                //通信失敗
                NSLog(@"失敗Error: %@", error);
            }];
  }
```

■補足情報

> データベース名：test
>   テーブル名：test_json
>   フィールド１：field_A
>   フィールド２：field_B
>   フィールド３：field_C
>   Apache/2.4.6 (MSMP)
>   PHP/5.6.30
>   PostgreSQL 10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーの発生している行数で利用している関数
`pg_connect`のPHPのリファレンスご確認ください。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.pg-connect.php

コネクションの書き方は基本的に文字列で渡す必要があります

```
$this->link=pg_connect("host={$this->dbServer} dbname={$this->dbName} user={$this->dbUser} password={$this->dbPass}");
```

また、引数で渡すやり方は非推奨になっているのでご注意ください。

> 複数のパラメータをサポートする古い構文 $conn = pg_connect("host", "port", "options",
>   "tty", "dbname") は推奨されません。

おそらく古いPHPで利用していたクラスから持ってきているかと思いますが、
まずは最新のリファレンスを確認していただき、関数やパラメータの使い方があっているかご確認したほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: 上記の件、ご教示頂き有難うございます。
ご指摘頂きましたコネクションの書き方へ修正致しましたところ、
通信は成功するようになりましたが、何故か3つのフィールド共に
「"field_A" = "<null>”;」を送信されるようで御座います。
関数やパラメータの使い方に問題がないか今一度確認致します！
解決致しましたら、ご報告できればと存じます。明日、また調査致します！
お忙しい中、ご教示頂き有難うございました！

Comment: 失礼致しました。私の勘違いでございました。上記の修正で問題解決致しました！大変助かりました！ご教示頂き有難うございました。もう少しPHP、ポスグレ勉強致します！